# iFrame box, how do I remove?

Tags: html

I'm going to send a php file in contact form without refreshing page via iFrame.
When I add the `<iframe name="frame"></iframe>` I get [this](https://gyazo.com/a134edeb137bdf661f61f10f229630b2) on the bottom of the page. How to remove?

If I remove `<iframe name="frame"></iframe>` the white box disappears.

Bottom of page:

```html
<iframe name="frame"></iframe>
```

In form tag:

````html
<form target="frame" class="contact-form" method="post" name="ContactForm" onsubmit="return SetText();" action="contact.php">```
````

Comment: Server request - response in background?? Try using `Ajax`

Comment: So what you want? To remove or not?

Comment: You don't need that iframe to send a form. The `target='frame'` on form just displays server response to the iframe. This isn't necessary in production it's just a way to confirm a 200.

Comment: @ShivCK Oh, I forgot. Yes I want to remove. I dont really know how to use ajax

Comment: @zer00ne If I don't use the `<iframe name="frame"></iframe>` and  `target="frame"` in the html file it reloads the page when I click submit

Comment: You can learn more about Ajax on any tutorial website. Ajax is mainly used to send request to server and retrieve response from it without refreshing the page. You can submit your form without page refresh.

Comment: @RandomguyfromSweden review my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56227868/2813224)

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove the iframe -- ***hide the iframe***. Wrap iframe in a block level element (ex. `<div>` or any **non-void** element with `display:block` (void elements do not have an end tag ex. `</div>`)). Then apply the following styles:

```
 position: relative;
 display: block; // if not already
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 1px;
 height: 1px;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: hidden
```

Next apply the following styles to the iframe:

```
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden
```

#### Demo Outline

1. Click the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button.
2. Click the <kbd>Toggle Iframe</kbd> button.
3. There should be a confirmation of a successful submission displayed in the iframe.

The areas with the comment `[OPTIONAL]` designate parts not required and are included for demonstration only.

```js
/* [OPTIONAL] All JavaScript */
const F = document.forms[0].elements;
F.toggle.onclick = toggleMask;

function toggleMask(e) {
  F.mask.classList.toggle('x');
}
```

```css
[name=mask] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* [OPTIONAL] width and height */
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.x {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  opacity: 0;
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<form action='https://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php' method='post' target='frame'>

  <input name='text' value='test'>
  <input type='submit'><br><br>


  <output name='mask' class='x'>
   <iframe src='https://example.com' name="frame"></iframe>
  </output>

  <!--[OPTIONAL] Toggle button-->
  <input id='toggle' type='button' value='Toggle Iframe'>

</form>
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I will try that.

Another question: How do I set a confirmation text (like a p tag with class/id) in php?

I have tried this, but it doesn't work. I dont really know why.

        `echo "<span class='mail-Empty'>Please, fill in all fields.</span>";`
        `echo "<span class='mail-EmailEmpty'>Please, write a correct email address.</span>";`

Comment: Sorry I'm only frontend, you should ask a new question.

Comment: Uhm. I got a problem with your snippet/snippets.

I did everything and the big white bottom thing in the bottom is removed. BUT. On the top of the page I got this; https://gyazo.com/b073ee379f2c485f2b9aff615d5bd742

I tried to set `z-index: 1;` on the `iframe` in the css, it didn't work either.

Comment: Hey, another problem..

I use google recaptcha (iframe) but when I do z-index to the iframe the google recaptcha disappears too, any idea?

Comment: 3rd party iframes are tricky if you try to cover them up and/or prevent basic functions. You need to research the API documentation and/or ask a new question.